# Linux ROS path camera info manager

Tags: ros

I would like to install bebop_autonomy(http://bebop-autonomy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). For this, I use, in a virtual box, ubuntu 14.04. I installed ROS indigo with the ros-indigo-desktop package. I followed every tutorials but at the last command line I have a problem.

```
*[build] Found '5' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                     
[build] Package table is up to date.                                           
Starting  >>> bebop_description                                                
Finished  <<< bebop_description                [ 3.1 seconds ]                 
Starting  >>> bebop_msgs                                                       
Finished  <<< bebop_msgs                       [ 2 minutes and 16.9 seconds ]                                                                                                                               
Starting  >>> bebop_driver                                                                                                                                                                                  
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Errors     << bebop_driver:cmake /home/hakim/bebop_ws/logs/bebop_driver/build.cmake.001.log                                                                                                                 
CMake Warning at /home/hakim/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "camera_info_manager" with any of the following names:

    camera_info_managerConfig.cmake

    camera_info_manager-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "camera_info_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "camera_info_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "camera_info_manager" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


CMake Error at /home/hakim/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "camera_info_manager" with any of the following names:

    camera_info_managerConfig.cmake

    camera_info_manager-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "camera_info_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  or set "camera_info_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "camera_info_manager" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


cd /home/hakim/bebop_ws/build/bebop_driver; catkin build --get-env bebop_driver | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/cmake /home/hakim/bebop_ws/src/bebop_autonomy/bebop_driver --no-warn-unused-cli -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/hakim/bebop_ws/devel/.private/bebop_driver -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/hakim/bebop_ws/install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo; cd -
............................................................................................................................................................................................................
Failed     << bebop_driver:cmake               [ Exited with code 1 ]                                                                                                                                       
Failed    <<< bebop_driver                     [ 16.6 seconds ]                                                                                                                                             
Abandoned <<< bebop_tools                      [ Unrelated job failed ]                                                                                                                                     
[build] Summary: 2 of 4 packages succeeded.                                                                                                                                                                 
[build]   Ignored:   1 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.                                                                                                                                            
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                                                                                                                                                  
[build]   Abandoned: 1 packages were abandoned.                                                                                                                                                             
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.                                                                                                                                                                     
[build] Runtime: 2 minutes and 49.4 seconds total.*
```

Comment: So, you need to install camera info manager? What's the question?

Comment: I have already install camera info manager but I don't understand the problem

Comment: It's either not installed in a default location or its broken. Check the CMakeError.log. And you might want to add the path to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this error too. Make sure you've installed the `ros-indigo-camera-info-manager` package. There are a few packages with "camera-info-manager" in the name, but that's the one needed.